# Javascript confirmation dialog box takes three clicks of "cancel" to close

Tags: javascript, dialog

The following code is guilty of generating this unusual problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    $t.parent().parent().remove();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Here's the HTML:

```
<td> <%= Html.ActionLink("<-Delete", "Delete", new {quoteID = quote.QuoteID}, new {@class= "deleteRow"}) %></td>

<td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/56">&lt;-Delete</a></td>
```

There we are.

```
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
    asd</p>
&lt;div firebugversion=&quot;1.5.4&quot; id=&quot;_firebugConsole&quot; style=&quot;display: none;&quot;&gt;

    &amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

            </td>
            <td>
                2345
            </td>
            <td>
                7/28/2010 3:26:10 PM
            </td>

            <td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/56">&lt;-Delete</a></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    $t.parent().parent().remove();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their parties.
            </td>

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                7/6/2010 10:13:44 PM
            </td>
            <td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/2">&lt;-Delete</a></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    $t.parent().parent().remove();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                I&#39;m a loser
            </td>
            <td>
                146
            </td>
            <td>

                7/6/2010 9:11:42 PM
            </td>
            <td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/1">&lt;-Delete</a></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    $t.parent().parent().remove();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
```

Thanks for all the responses, btw.

Comment: what is the HTML element with the class="deleteRow" ? Also what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you also please post the section of HTML this is acting upon?

Comment: Is it possible this code is running multiple times?

Comment: I have the impresiion that the confirm is called for each .deleterow.  Is it possible you have 3 objects with deleterow class ?

Comment: I DO in fact have three!  

I'm whiffing on the connection still, though...

Comment: What does the generated HTML, not the template, read like? @nealv it's possible, but that's not very likely for a click event, is it? Perhaps if the markup is malformed.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML that is output to the page, so we can see how many Buttons you have and what type of button they are? Submit or Button

Comment: Also, which browser are you using for testing? Does it do it in all browsers?

Comment: You still need to post the containing HTML that encapsulates all three elements that have class "deleteRow". That will be the key to solving this problem.

Comment: I am not having a problem with the cancel button working in my sample code, closes first time, need more HTML

Comment: Oh, and which jQuery version - are you using 1.4.2?

Comment: Posted the table.

Version 1.4.1

Comment: I'm a real amateur, in case you haven't noticed.  Thanks for the patience.

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for. Every one was once an amateur.

Comment: See my updated answer for a lengthy discussion of event binding.

Comment: Woohoo!  I was going nuts for a while.
I appreciate the help fellas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that you've posted the generated HTML, it's plain to see that you've put the jQuery output inside the loop that generates your TD elements. It should go outside that loop, preferably at the bottom of the page!

If you look at the HTML, you'll see this 3 times:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        if (confirm('Delete?')) {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    $t.parent().parent().remove();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Now, you **might** say "yeah, it's defined three times, but shouldn't it still execute once? After all, I'm redeclaring the click handler!". Well, no. jQuery's .click() method binds a function to a particular event by adding that function to the list of eventListeners for that event. This is how event binding works in general in Javascript. Binding means add it to the list.

If you want to make sure the click handler you are adding is the ONLY click handler for a element, you'd have to use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) first :

```
 $('.deleteRow').unbind('click').click(function (event) { // rest of code...
```

instead of this:

```
 $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) { // rest of code...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I've found that I'm pretty far out to sea now that I'm incorporating jQuery into my app.

Comment: @PolishedTurd, you'll get it. If you have more questions, ask them here. Just always make sure you're posting actual HTML output, as you can see it got you your answer right away. Once you're up and running with jQuery, you'll never look back.

Comment: I have a hard time reading it sometimes, keeping track of the big chains and matching up all the parenthesis and braces - lol.

Answer (score 2):

BINGO ~ you only need to call the event binder ONCE!

you are doing it three times.

bottom of the page should only have one script block

Also:

when you do this:

```
$t = $(this);
```

that query is now stored in $t so you can reuse it.

```
$.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
```

can just use the stored result set

```
$.post($t.attr('href'), function (data) {
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks.  You actually pointed out another issue I was having that involved scope and "this."

Answer (score 1):

I made this test page using the info you supplied. It doesn't exhibit this behavior. (I added TRs, but it doesn't make a difference - it worked normally before, too).

What differs between your own test page and this example?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.deleteRow').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (confirm('Delete?')) {
                        var $t = $(this);
                        $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                            if (data) {
                                $t.parent().parent().remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

   </head>
   <body>
     <table>
       <tr><td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/56">&lt;-Delete</a></td></tr>
       <tr><td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/56">&lt;-Delete</a></td></tr>
       <tr><td> <a class="deleteRow" href="/Quote/Delete/56">&lt;-Delete</a></td></tr>
     </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: check if your 'if(data)' is triggered. maybe you don't return 'true'